# Alternative to deprecated SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK

Tags: android, kotlin

Previously, I could get the device to turn on the screen when a new notification arrived by aquiring a wakelock for a few seconds in the `onMessageReceived` method. But the SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated now ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK)). The docs suggest using the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` instead, but as I am just building the notification with the default system template, so I'm not sure how I would call the `WindowManager` of the system notification heads-up window. Is it possible or is there another way of doing this?

Previously I had something like this.

```kotlin
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

    val pm = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    val isScreenOn =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 20) pm.isInteractive else pm.isScreenOn  
    if (!isScreenOn) {
        val wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
            "irfAuroraAlert:newNotificationWakeLock"
        )
        wl.acquire(3000)}

    remoteMessage.data.let {
        it["new_alert"]?.let { body -> sendNotification(body) }
    }
    remoteMessage.notification?.let {
        it.body?.let { body -> sendNotification(body) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Scrolling up a bit on the page the docs link to, it seems to show how to use these under [FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED)

Comment: But I would still need to access the `Activity` of the default notification, I'm not sure how I could do that?